# What's the best practise for showing up a modal after fetch data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my App()

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";

const ComponentTest = () => {
  const { _sid } = useParams();
  const [sid, setsid] = useState(_sid);
  const [myData, setmyData] = useState({
    message: "",
    file: "",
    createTime: "",
  });

  const onClick = async () => {
    const resopnse = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5100/api/get?_sid=" + sid);
    const resopnseJson = await resopnse.json();
    setmyData({
      ...myData,
      message: resopnseJson.message,
      file: resopnseJson.file,
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="btn btn-outline-primary form-control"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#myModal"
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        Test
      </button>

      <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem is when the button is clicked, the modal appears then data is loaded.
What I want is: First fetch data, then show up the modal.

Do I need to use useEffect? and how? Thanks!
Any good ways to learn hooks?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite understand, while I click the button, it actually fetched data and set myData, however myData return an empty object first time. 
If insert a console.log(myData)  before return, I load this component and click button, console print [], and click again, console print myData with fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue which needs to be resolved is the modal showing up without a condition. So go ahead and wrap the modal container div with a condition which will always render the modal (will change this in later):

```
const YourComponent = () => {
    ....
    return (
        <div>
            <button>Test</button>
            {true === true ? <div class="modal" id="myModal">...</div> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This way, you are not just rendering the modal, you are also controlling its render. Next you have to figure out a way to set the value of the condition placeholder (`true === true`). This can be done with `state`, but looking at your code, I think that it is easier and more efficient to add a flag in your data state and set it to true whenever you get a response. Then use that flag to see if the modal should or should not render:

```
const ComponentTest = () => {
    const { _sid } = useParams();
    const [sid, setsid] = useState(_sid);
    const [myData, setmyData] = useState({
        message: "",
        file: "",
        createTime: "",
        loaded: false
    });

    const onClick = async () => {
        const resopnse = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5100/api/get?_sid=" + sid)
        const resopnseJson = await resopnse.json();
        setmyData(
            { ...myData, message: resopnseJson.message, file: resopnseJson.file, loaded: true }
        )
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="btn btn-outline-primary form-control" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal" onClick={onClick}>Test</button>

            {myData.loaded === true ? <div class="modal" id="myModal">...</div> : null}
        </div>
    )

}
```